# Filepicker.io rendered images don't thumbnail in Twitter

Tags: filepicker.io

We're just starting to use Filepicker.io in a project and had a question about rendering thumbnails. Our [first test image](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/1S7rGZDSRX2OF3x9bxb1) does not appear to be recognized by Twitter as an image. This means that all the user will see is a link instead of the thumbnail.

Is there any way around this behaviour, perhaps with some sort of custom URL or optional parameter?

**UPDATE**

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="upload-image">Drop files here</div>

// init filepicker plugin
filepicker.makeDropPane($('.upload-image'), {
    multiple: true,
    dragEnter: function() {
        $(".upload-image").html("Drop to upload").css({
            'backgroundColor': "#E0E0E0",
            'border': "1px solid #000"
        });
        console.log('enter');
    },
    dragLeave: function() {
        $(".upload-image").html("Drop files here").css({
            'backgroundColor': "#F6F6F6",
            'border': "1px dashed #666"
        });
    },
    onSuccess: function(fpfiles) {
        $(".upload-image").text("Done, see result below");
        $.sticky('Your file was uploaded successfully.');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(fpfiles));
    },
    onError: function(type, message) {
        // $("#localDropResult").text('('+type+') '+ message);
        $.sticky('Your file was uploaded successfully.');
    },
    onProgress: function(percentage) {
        $(".upload-image").text("Uploading ("+percentage+"%)");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is append a +filename.jpg to the end of the image if twitter (or really any other service) is doing a simple regex, url-based determination of whether the file is an image. For instance:

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JhJKMtnRDW9uLYcnkRKW and 
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JhJKMtnRDW9uLYcnkRKW+fry.png

both point to the same content, but twitter may be happier with the second.

Comment: We decided to build our own display page containing Twitter and Open graph cards. Then we simply use the filepicker image.